# Multiple COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(field AS DATE) in one query

Tags: mysql

I need to find the `count` of `distinct dates` based on 2 criteria (as a whole), but I also need to show the `distinct date` counts for each of the 2 criteria's.  Because the date field also includes a time, I am using:
`COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(se.SeriesDate AS DATE))`, which works just fine.  But I'm struggling including the same count for each of the 2 criteria's in my WHERE clause.

I have tried:

```
SELECT ID,
COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(se.SeriesDate AS DATE)) VISITS,
COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(se.SeriesDate AS DATE) CASE WHEN se.Manufacture LIKE 'CIRRUS%' THEN se.SeriesDate END) Cirrus,
COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(se.SeriesDate AS DATE) CASE WHEN se.Manufacture LIKE 'Glaucoma%' THEN se.SeriesDate END) Glaucoma
From patient
WHERE (se.Manufacture LIKE 'CIRRUS%' OR se.Manufacture LIKE 'Glaucoma%'
GROUP BY ID
```

I would like it to return this (these are distinct visit dates):

```
Visits: 9
Cirrus: 6
Glaucoma: 3
```

This obviously doesn't work but after trying to research `CAST` and `CASE` together, I'm not finding anything. If this wasn't a date field, I understand how to do this. Has anyone done this before? TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional aggregation syntax:

```
SELECT ID,
COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(se.SeriesDate AS DATE)) VISITS,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN se.Manufacture LIKE 'CIRRUS%' 
                    THEN CAST(se.SeriesDate AS DATE) END) Cirrus,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN se.Manufacture LIKE 'Glaucoma%' 
                    THEN CAST(se.SeriesDate AS DATE) END) Glaucoma
From patient
WHERE (se.Manufacture LIKE 'CIRRUS%' OR se.Manufacture LIKE 'Glaucoma%')
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: I thought this was going to work, but it returns incorrect data.  If I just use the first Count statement, the correct number of visits is returned. But when I add in the 2 additional count statements, the numbers are incorrect.

Comment: Actually I do think it is returning correctly. It turns out the db still leaves an entry, even if the visit images were deleted.  Thank you so much for your help!  Much appreciated!

Comment: If this answer worked for you should select it as the correct answer. :)